# how to set a default value in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

In the database there is class Borrowing which contains employee_id that will borrow item and tag_id (the item) and subscriber_id

in my code, if an employee request a borrowing, he can choose subscriber_id.
I need to set the  subscriber_id to 1, without even asking the employee to choose.

in the models.py file

```
class Borrowing(models.Model):
borrowing_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
tag_id = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
subscriber_id = models.ManyToManyField(Subscriber)

def __str__(self): 
    return str(self.borrowing_id)
```

in forms.py file

```
class BorrowingForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Borrowing
    fields = ['end_date', 'employee_id', 'tag_id', 'subscriber_id']
```

in views.py

```
def createBorrowing(request, pk):
BorrowingFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Employee, Borrowing, fields=('end_date','tag_id','subscriber_id'))
employee = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)
formset = BorrowingFormSet(queryset=Borrowing.objects.none(), instance=employee)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = BorrowingFormSet(request.POST, instance=employee)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return redirect('/login')

context = {'formset':formset}
return render(request, 'assetstracking/createBorrowing.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set a default value in the Models.py

```
class Borrowing(models.Model):
    ...
    subscriber_id = models.ManyToManyField(Subscriber, default=default_subscriber)
    ...
    
    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.borrowing_id)
```

And if you don't need the employee to chose you can remove subscriber_id from the fields in the forms.py

Notice that default_subscriber needs to be a subscriber.